# Python PyGame KEYDOWN not working

Tags: python, input, menu, keyboard, pygame

I have no idea why this isn't working but it doesn't capture the keydown. Clicking cross works fine and exits the game. It i probably something simple but I can't see it. The keydown works fine in the other parts of my program it is just the main menu that does not work. Here is the code for the menu section:

```
        while menuOver == False:

            Screen.fill(background_colour)
            font1 = pygame.font.SysFont("Impact", 100)
            font2 = pygame.font.SysFont("Impact", 50)
            font3 = pygame.font.SysFont("Impact", 25)
            lblTitle = font1.render("Python", 100, (black))
            Screen.blit(lblTitle, (265, 50))

            lblSubTitle = font2.render("Created With Python", 100, (black))
            Screen.blit(lblSubTitle, (200, 200))

            lblEasy = font3.render('Easy - Press 1', 100, (red))
            Screen.blit(lblEasy, (100, 300))

            lblNormal = font3.render('Normal - Press 2', 100, (red))
            Screen.blit(lblNormal, (300, 300))

            lblNightmare = font3.render('Nightmare - Press 3', 100, (red))
            Screen.blit(lblNightmare, (525, 300))

            lblLeaderboard = font3.render('Press L To View Leaderboard', 100, (black))
            Screen.blit(lblLeaderboard, (90, 400))

            lblInstructions = font3.render('Press I To View Instructions', 100, (black))
            Screen.blit(lblInstructions, (425, 400))

            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                    if event.type == pygame.K_1:

                        menuOver = True
```

Comment: You have to check `event.key == pygame.K_1`, not `event.type == pygame.K_1`

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! Thanks for pointing it out it's had me stuck for ages!.

Comment: Might the people who donwvoted explain why? Teds comment is the correct answer, and i had the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you typed `event.type == pygame.K_1:`, but it is supposed to be `if event.key == pygame.K_1`.

When you type `for event in pygame.event.get():`, it inserts each element of `pygame.event.get()` into `event`, one at a time.  `event` returns the event type when you use `event.type`, and the key pressed, if relevant, when you use `event.key`.

Refer to https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html for more information.

EDIT: Sorry, I just realized your question was answered in the comments...

Comment: It is still good to post the answer because this is thorough and new programmers will find it helpful